# Filtering SQL query in PowerShell with WHERE

Tags: sql, powershell

first post here. I'm getting my app development feet wet with some PowerShell scripting; I know it's not the best for developing GUI applications but it's what I'm familiar with and the best way I know of to interact with Office 365 applications, which my employees have to do a lot of.

I'm trying to build functions to make it easy to populate combo boxes, read user input from the combobox, and then query an Access database for specific results based on that input.

I've got another function that queries the database to pull a list that populates a combobox. now, i want to build a separate function that

1. "reads" the user's input from the combobox
2. opens an OleDB connection to query the access database
3. scans the database table for the row corresponding to the user's input
4. returns, as a string, the cell in a different column from the same row the user chose

this is what i have so far:

```
 function Read-BoxSelection ($sourceBox, $sourceTable, $sourceColumn, $targetColumn){
     $conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
     $conn.ConnectionString = $connString
     $conn.Open() | Out-Null

     $cmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
     $cmd.Connection = $conn

     $selectedID = $sourceBox.SelectedItem

     [string]$writeQuery = ("SELECT * FROM $($sourceTable) WHERE $($sourceColumn) = $($selectedID)")

     $cmd.CommandText = "$writeQuery" 

     $reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

     while ($reader.read()){
        $readerResult = $reader.getValue($reader.GetOrdinal("$targetColumn"))
        return $readerResult  
     }

     $reader.close()
     $conn.close()
 }
```

I am sure the while() loop will need to change; it's pulled over from the earlier function that populates the combobox with the contents of the $sourceColumn.

**The issue:** my first function was called Get-BoxData. it opens the connection, runs a query, and uses the while() loop to Items.Add each cell from the $targetColumn to the combo box. for Get-BoxData function, the following code worked fine to execute the SQL query:

```
[string]$readQuery = ("SELECT * FROM $($targetTable)")

$cmd.CommandText = "$readQuery"

$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

but when I change the query for Read-BoxSelection - namely, to filter the result based on user input with WHERE - **the command doesn't get passed to ExecuteReader no matter what I do**. This is very strange, because I placed a breakpoint at the ExecuteReader line, and Write-Host confirms that both $writeQuery and $cmd.CommandText have successfully picked up the query exactly as written. stranger still is that previously, debugging ExecuteReader issues would involve a syntax error in the SQL query; here, I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "No value given for one or more required parameters."
```

Not sure how to proceed here!

Comment: Please show the `Write-Host` output of SQL query. `ExecuteReader` errors does indicate command was reached. You need to enclose string literals in `WHERE` with quotes. Even better use [parameterization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

Comment: Also show how you call the function. Have you set sourceColumn and targetColumn?

Comment: @parfait Write-Host at the breakpoint returns the whole text of $query as expected, i.e. "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = myCellContents"

Comment: What is `myCellContents`? String, number? If this SQL is literally passed as is into MS Access, it will raise an error of unknown parameter.

Comment: it is defined in the database as Short Text, and by my code as [string]

Answer (score 1):

String literals in SQL must be enclosed in quotes whether used in `SELECT`, `JOIN`, or `WHERE` clauses. Otherwise the database engine will consider the object an identifier (table, column, etc.) or parameter. MS Access treats any unquoted, named object not recognized in table as a parameter.

Therefore, the short answer is to wrap `WHERE` condition value in single quotes since as you comment is a string value:

```bsh
[string]$writeQuery = ("SELECT * FROM $($sourceTable) WHERE $($sourceColumn) = '$($selectedID)'")
```

However, the preferred answer is to use [parameterization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) which can easily be done since you already set up the command object:

```bsh
# PREPARED STATEMENT WITH ? PLACEHOLDER
[string]$writeQuery = ("SELECT * FROM $($sourceTable) WHERE $($sourceColumn) = ?")     
$cmd.CommandText = $writeQuery

# ADD AND BIND PARAMETER
$cmd.Parameters.Add("@param", [System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType]::VarChar, 255)
$cmd.Parameters["@param"].Value = $selectedID

$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
```